# .htaccess Error 500 when using <Directory> because Apache

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I want to use a .htaccess with  to deny the access to a folder:

```
<Directory "/private">
    deny from all
</Directory>
```

But I get the following Error: /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/.htaccess:

I use Xampp

Comment: But I get the following Error: /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/.htaccess: Directory not allowed here

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR* just place

```
Deny from all
```

without the enclosing `Directory` in your .htaccess file.

Because you want to restrict `Deny` to directory `private`, you must place the .htaccess file in the subdirectory `private` and not in the document root.

---

Both [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#directory)

> `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories.

and [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) files

> .htaccess files provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis.

serve the same purpose.

The difference between the two is just where they might be used. `Directory` may be used in server config and virtual host context, whereas .htaccess files are placed in the appropriate directory.